# Why Does this particular code throw an exeption?

Tags: c, pointers, exception, linked-list, nullptr

Critical error detected c0000374

```
#pragma once

typedef struct node
{
int value;
node* next;
node* before;
}   node;

void print_nodes(node* list) {
node *current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
//current->value = 0;
current->next = list;

while (current->next != nullptr) {
    printf("%i\n", current->next->value); <-THROW an Exception in the Fist loop
    current->next = current->next->next;
}
free(current);
}

void add_node(node* list) {

}

inline void new_nodes(node* list, size_t anzahl) {
list[0].before = NULL;
for (int i = 0; i <= anzahl; i++) {
    list[i].value = i + 1;
    list[i].next = &list[i + 1];
    list[i + 1].next = &list[i - 1];
}
list[anzahl].next = NULL;
}
```

The printf statement Throws an Exception ... but only sometimes.
My cpp calls the function new_nodes with the size_t = 10 so it cant be tooooo big.

Additional Info one time even the heap "broke".

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Additional Info one time even the heap "broke"

Comment: This `current->next = current->next->next;` is too dangerous as what if `current->next->next` is `NULL` and next time in `while()` loop condition you are going to check `NULL->next`, it cause crash. Also I don't understand why you are doing malloc in `print_nodes()` function ? `add_nodes()` already creates the list, `print_nodes()` has to just print it.

Comment: The print_nodes() malloc is only for current it only allocate memory for one instance

Comment: "is too dangerous as what if current->next->next is NULL and next time in while() loop condition you are going to check NULL->next" What would be your suggestion

Comment: Add the extra info to the question, please, rather than in comments.  The `malloc()` in the print code isn’t needed.  You could write the code with a local pointer variable.

Comment: u mean like this?               `void print_nodes(node* list) {
 node current;
 //current->value = 0;
 current.next = list;

 while (current.next != nullptr) {
  printf("%i\n", current.next->next->value);
  current.next = current.next->next;
 }
 
}`

Comment: The simple check can be `list != nullptr` and anyhow you are just printing list in the `print_nodes()` function not modifying it, therefore use the same `list` argument to print it. For e.g `void print_nodes(node* list) {
        while (list != nullptr) {
                printf("%i\n", list->value);
                list = list->next;
        }       
}`

Comment: Tried it still throws an exception :(

Comment: Exception, casting the result of `malloc`, `nullptr`, "cpp" ... are you sure about the C tag? Maybe change it to C++ tag?

Comment: Yeah cheated a little with the nullptr keyword but vs is not able to let me use c keywords only so i thought why not

Comment: but i casted the result of malloc with the standart c-style cast so no problemo there

Comment: _no problemo there_ -- yes problemo. You didn't `#include <stdlib.h>`, did you? Meanwhile, show the code which calls `new_nodes`.

Comment: Yes i did include stdlib.h

Comment: do NOT place function bodies in a header file,   Move the function to a separate file and have the header file ONLY contain the prototype for the function.

Comment: regarding: `void add_node(node* list) { }`
  and 
`void add_node(node* list,node*) { }`  overloading function names is NOT allowed in C.  So this must be C++.  Please correct the 'tag' from `c` to `c++`

Comment: The posted code is a mix of C and C++ code.  Use only a single language, don't mix the languages

Comment: regarding: `new_nodes()`  This is the function that needs to allocate a new node, fill in the fields of that new node, then link it into the `list`  Exactly how to link the new node into the `list` will depend on some info not provided in the question, such as 1) is it a circular list 2) link at the beginning of `list` 3) link at the end of `list` 4) link at the ascending (or descending) ordered point in the `list`  Therefore we cannot say exactly what is wrong with that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this:

```
void print_nodes(node* list) 
{
    node *current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    //current->value = 0;
    current->next = list;

    while (current->next != nullptr) 
    {
        printf("%i\n", current->next->value); <-THROW an Exception in the Fist loop
        current->next = current->next->next;
    }
    free(current);
}
```

Needs to be heavily modified:  Suggest:

modified (after clarification by the OP) to use a 'headless' linked list

```
void print_nodes(node* list) 
{ 
    node * current = list; 

    while (current) 
    { 
        printf("%i\n", current->value); 
        current = current->next; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Good Suggestion modified it to `void print_nodes(node* list) {
 while (list->next != NULL) {
  printf("%i\n", list->value);
  list = list->next;
 } 
}`

Comment: I`m not quite sure if this maybe cause some trouble

Comment: This would be your "code" "implemented" and "working" `void print_nodes(node* list) {
 node * current = list;
 while (current->next != NULL) {
  printf("%i\n", current->value);
  current = current->next;
 } 
}`

Comment: @TimWeissenfels,  Your suggested code assumes that there is no 'head' pointer for the list.  I assumed that there would be a 'head' pointer that contains nothing but a pointer to the first entry in the list

Comment: Yeah you are right thats why i used your code and changed it a bit to fit my needs

Comment: @TimWeissenfels,  If you like my answer, then please accept it.

Comment: Accepted it but change the code to my "correction" of it because your code would print out 1 element "further than wished"

Comment: @TimWeissenfels,  Actually my version of the code would stop at the right time.  However, since you have not implemented a 'head' pointer, it would skip the first entry.  I'll edit the code to use your suggested version.

Comment: Yeah but my code is working in my particular version thats why. Bcs i mean ur code is the proper way to do it but i wouldent work in my case

Comment: Maybe u accept my edit and edit it into :working code with this code x: and :working code with this code y: or something like that